# Having issues writing to EditText in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-edittext, kotlin

So I think I'm having some scoping issues.
I'm trying to use the function **setZipEdit** to set the `R.id.zipHolder` `editText` in my activity. I'm just having issues in setting up the code to be able to do this. Below is what I have which isn't currently working. `mZipHold` is coming back as not `initialized` which I though it was in the `override`

**UPDATED**

```
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var townInfo:JsonArray<JsonObject>


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2)


    SET_TOWN.setOnClickListener {v -> setTowns()}
    GET_TOWNS.setOnClickListener {v -> retrieveTowns()}


}
 fun setZipEdit(zipEdit:String){
    Log.d("SZE",zipEdit)
     zipHolder.setText(zipEdit)



     //mZipHold.setText(zipEdit,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)

}
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
>                                                                                      at
>
> **com.example.sdfsdf.listview.SecondActivity._$_findCachedViewById(SecondActivity.kt:0)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.example.sdfsdf.listview.SecondActivity.setZipEdit(SecondActivity.kt:44)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.example.sdfsdf.listview.SecondActivity$MyCustomAdapter$onCreateViewHolder$1.onClick(SecondActivity.kt:124)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)**
>                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/returnimage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="logoforZip"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_new_icon_plain" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/zipHolder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="ZIP HERE"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/returnimage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SET_TOWN"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="SET TOWN"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/zipHolder"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/zipHolder"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/zipHolder" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/GET_TOWNS"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="LIST NEARBY TOWNS"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/SET_TOWN"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/SET_TOWN"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SET_TOWN" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/splitbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/GET_TOWNS" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/zipList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#222222"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/splitbar" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: why are you not using kotlinextension @BostonMacOSX

Comment: I have them in there but having issues with picking up items I've put into my layouts.

Comment: can you update your code with import or XML file here

Comment: this code is not enough to figure out the issue

Comment: Updated with XML

Answer (score 1):

Ok, But using kotlinextension is a better way to do this, I think you need to do 2 things may solve your problem

**first**

`import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main2.*`

I think which you have already done

**second** instead of initializing your `Editext` by `findViewById` direct use as

```
fun setZipEdit(zipEdit:String){
        Log.d("SZE",zipEdit)
        Log.d("mzh",mZipHold.toString())
         zipHolder.setText(zipEdit)

         //mZipHold.setText(zipEdit,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)

    }
```

you can access your views by only use their id. Let try this and let me know if works

Comment: Hello zipHOlder.text requires Editable! but zipEdit is a string..so setText(String) is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, I have updated my code as you see above and @BostonMacOSX this is working at my side and hopefully this will works at you too

Comment: you dont need to init view inside initialize block. kotlin syntectic has lazy initialization for bind views.

Comment: Yeah, I knows and am not intializing any view in init block,